# First Unique Character in a String Leetcode - using pointers (javascript)

Tags: javascript, pointers, data-structures

Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return its index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

[leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/)

```
"cc"            // -1
"ccdd"          // -1
"leetcode"      // 1
"loveleetcode"  // 2
"abcabd"        // 2
"thedailybyte"  // 1
"developer"     // 0
```

My approach passed all the test cases except the 2nd test case `"ccdd"`. I am expecting `-1` but receiving `4`. Not sure why.

```
var firstUniqChar = function(s) {
    if(!s || s.length === 0 )  return -1
    else if(s.length === 1)    return 0
    
    let pointer1 = 0
    let pointer2 = pointer1 + 1
    
    if(s.length > 2){
        while(pointer2 <= s.length - 1){
            if(s[pointer1] !== s[pointer2])
                pointer2++
            else if(s[pointer1] === s[pointer2])
                pointer1++
            }
        
        return pointer1
    }
    return -1
    
};
```

Comment: Some helpful questions to guide your debugging: what happens when `pointer1 >= pointer2`? What should happen? What should the method return if `pointer1 >= s.length`?

Comment: If I change the while statement to `pointer1 >= pointer2`  or `pointer1 >= s.length` it returns `0` , instead of `-1` . It also returns `0` for the other test cases, such as `"loveleetcode" `

Answer (score 0):

this is too old, but still can be too much shorter:

```
const firstUniqChar = (_str) => {
  for (let i= 0; i < _str.length; i+= 1) {
    if (_str.indexOf(_str[i]) === _str.lastIndexOf(_str[i])) return i+1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```